# Math question related to functional equations

Tags: functional-equations

The function $f$ satisfies
$f(x) + f(2x + y) + 5xy = f(3x - y) + 2x^2 + 1$for all real numbers $x$, $y$. Determine the value of $f(10)$.

Comment: What have you determined about this function so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meanwhile, there really is such a function,
$$ f(w) = -\frac{1}{2} w^2 + 1 $$
works

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=10, y=5$. Then the condition becomes
$$f(10)+f(25)+250=f(25)+201$$
Which implies that $f(10)=-49$.

Comment: @Will Jagy and pwerth:  Putting $x=2y$ the equation gives $f(2y)=-2y^2+1$ since in this case $2x+y=3x-y$. Therefore the solution above is the only one. One should however check that it *is* a solution.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger that's a good trick. The one thing I completed was assume $f(w) = a w^2 + b w + c,$ find the coefficients and confirm that it worked. I've never taught this kind of contest problem, i just know quadratic forms, so the problem caught my eye